# How to save file automatically after a new window opens in Selenium

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently generating reports on a website, and when i click the export link it opens a new window. The new window opens another window that asks if i want to open with excel or save file.

I want it to save the file automatically to my given location.

I was able to do this for other websites that do not open a new window to download.

[image]

after I click export to csv, the window with "your download is running.." pops up. Then the save or open window pops up.

This is my current profile settings for my webdrive:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv/xls')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, I am pretty sure in `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` setting.

Try the following:

```
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/plain,text/csv,application/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,text/comma-separat‌​ed-values,application/excel,application/octet-stream')
```

And, here is what we've actually debugged and discovered in chat:

```
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/download')
```

Also, here is a good read on how to let firefox detect the mime-type and use it:

- [Determining file MIME types to autosave using Firefox & Watir-WebDriver](http://watirmelon.com/2011/09/07/determining-file-mime-types-to-autosave-using-firefox-watir-webdriver/)

Comment: It does not work with the change. My current profile settings work for another website that does not open a new window to download. Do you think the profile settings are being transferred to the new window?

Comment: @George yup, it's a browser preference - it's applied to all of the windows. Can you share the link to this csv file so I can test it? Thanks.

Comment: @George I've also updated the answer, try it out with `text/csv,application/csv` mime type.

Comment: sorry I cannot provide the link because it requires a login

Comment: @George okay, have you tried to specify the MS Excel mime types? Also, a sanity check, are you passing the `profile` into the `webdriver.Firefox()` constructor?

Comment: I am reading the documentation on MS Excel mime types now. Yes I am passing it with  'driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)'